# Minimum sample size to observe certain outcomes

Tags: categorical-data

Given a categorical random variable with large number of possible outcomes and a sufficiently large sample, I observe that 90% of the sample falls into some relatively small number of categories, say, 30 out of 1000. How can I estimate minimum sample size such that these 30 categories are observed?

A sort of a solution is, I guess, to produce smaller datasets resampling with replacement from the original one.

Comment: A particular set of 30 categories, or at least 30 different unspecified categories? What is your goal? What kind of statistical analysis is planned?

Comment: @RussLenth Yes, a particular set of 30 most frequent categories. I'd like to merge the remaining categories into 'others', for the purpose of doing $\chi^2$ tests and stuff.

Comment: What are the probabilities of the 5 or so least frequent categories? Are you sampling from your dataset, or collecting new data?

Comment: @RussLenth Counts of the least frequent categories are 1. Original post is really a simplified description, actually I have thousands of categories and nearly 1/3 of them are observed once in 3 million sample. If the exact numbers are important, I can look it up.

Comment: @RussLenth I would like to estimate sample size when collecting new data. What I would like to do is to compare new samples to the original one, but using only most frequent categories + 'others' to avoid sparsness introduced by categories with low counts.

Comment: Sorry I meant the least frequent 5 or so from among those 30 key ones.

Comment: @RussLenth Oh, ok. In the actual sample I have 30000 categories, out of which top 1000 sums up to 90% of the sample. Least frequent categories have frequencies around 250/3000000.

Answer (score 2):

With the probability you provided of $250/3000000 = 8.33 \times 10^{-5}$, then in order to have a 99% probability of obtaining at least one observation in that category, you need $n \ge -\ln(1-.99) / (250/3000000) \approx 55300$.

However, to do $\chi^2$ tests and such, you generally want at least 5 observations in each category (the standard rule of thumb). You have less than half a chance of that happening with only $55.3$K observations. By experimenting, I was able to find that with $n=140,000$ observations, you have a bit more than a 99% chance of having at least 5 observations in that category.

Perhaps these sample sizes are larger than what you expected? Well, it isn't easy to collect enough data to do a $\chi^2$ test on 31 categories. Maybe you need to reduce your requirements...

Comment: So, in general, to estimate minimum sample size I need to calculate $-{ln(1-\alpha)\over \hat p}$? Could you please point out where this formula comes from?

Comment: It comes from the Poisson approximation and solving $.99 := P(X>0) = 1 - e^{-np}$